# Python + Scrapy + MySQL UTF8 Encoding error

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, scrapy

I have a scrapy code that scrapes a website and writes to MySQL

```
import MySQLdb.cursors

def __init__(self,stats):
    self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(<dbnam>,host=<host>,user=<user>,port=<port>,passwd=<pwd>, db=<dbname>, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor, charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
```

Scrapy script for a list of numbers in table

```
item['numbers'] = sites.xpath('//*[@id="numbers-0"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').extract()
```

I'm scraping the following content: 10″ 11″ 12″ etc. My code returns the following:

```
'numbers': [u'10\u2033', u'11\u2033', u'12\u2033'],
```

Inserting this into a MySQL db throws an error message - I'm guessing due to unicode issue.

```
tx.execute("""INSERT INTO numbers ('{0}').format(", ".join(item['numbers'])))
```

Could you please help get the insert to succeed. Better still, how can I remove the special character '\u2033' from the list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: 2.7.11 Thanks Bernard for looking into this!

Comment: No worries, would you mind trying to use [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) as opposed to the MySQL connector?

Comment: No problem at all with moving from MYSQL connector. I am new to Python and Scrapy. Just need to figure out how to use PyMySQL

Comment: Do exactly the same as you are with the connector, just put `pymysql` in place. And to install it run `sudo pip install PyMySQL`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not as advanced a user. I'v updated the question to include the connection string. Thanks a lot Bernard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting a `UnicodeEncodeError` because you are trying to insert unicode strings containing non-ascii characters into a byte-string.

To fix that, make sure your query string has a `u` prefix:

```
tx.execute(u"""INSERT INTO numbers ('{0}')""".format(", ".join(item['numbers'])))
```

If you really want to get get rid of those double-prime characters, I suppose you could just replace them with double-quotes:

```
item['numbers'] = [s.replace(u'\u2033', '"') for s in item['numbers']]
```

But I think it's better to ensure your code can handle whatever unicode characters are thrown at it - which is to say, you should *always* use unicode strings within your program.

Comment: I cant upvote your answer because I'm new to stackoverflow. Will be back once I earn some credibility! :)

Comment: @user6055239. Thanks :) NB: you can always [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), which will also earn you a little bit of rep.